# how to upgrade already hosted sharepoint site?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to Sharepoint(2010). I have given a Sharepoint site which is already hosted and I have to add some `EventReceiver` on a `FormLibrary`. So my question is how to add modify that hosted Sharepoint site.

Can someone please explain the process how to update (adding `eventreceiver(VS2010)` and deploy) Sharepoint Site.

I have installed Sharepoint Server 2010 and i know how to add `eventreceivers` to library/list on local Sharepoint site.

Comment: You're asking for a full tutorial on something you could research and learn yourself? SO isn't meant for that.

Comment: @NewAmbition :  Plz try to understand.. I know all the stuff i have maintained but only if sharepoint site is local. BUT suppose u have given a site url which is developed in Sharepoint...Then How You will add some feature to it(also require vs2010 to add features).

Answer (score 1):

after deploying the project on 'local site' you will get `WSP` file , take this file to server and deploy it using following powershell commands

adding wsp file

`Add-SPSolution c:\code\SharePointProject2\bin\debug\SharePointProject2.wsp`

istalling wsp file

`Install-SPSolution –Identity SharePointProject2.wsp –WebApplication http://sp2010 -GACDeployment`

for more details about these commands check this link .

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/12/02/adding-and-deploying-solutions-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: And don't forget to activate the feature as necessary